# Coredata - Multithreading best way

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

Parent_Context

Child_context (Set Parent_Context as parent)

Child_context to use in background to add new data or to update existing.
Parent_Context to display on UI and to save data persistent store.

Child_context save should not take time as changes are updated only in memory. That is updated to Parent_Context.

Parent_Context save might take time as it writes to store. So we can choose when to save Parent_Context based on the need of the application.

This is how I normally use context when needed in multithreaded environment or to update UI while still accessing data in background.

```
// Parent or main
_mainQueueContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
_mainQueueContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;

// Child or background context
_privateQueueContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[_privateQueueContext setParentContext:self.mainQueueContext]; // Set main threads MOC as parent.

//To Save
    if ([self privateQueueContext].hasChanges) {
        [[self privateQueueContext] performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSError *childError = nil;
            if ([[self privateQueueContext] save:&childError]) {
                [[self mainQueueContext] performBlock:^{
                    NSError *parentError = nil;
                    if (![[self mainQueueContext] save:&parentError]) {
                        DLog(@"Error saving parent, error: %@", [parentError localizedDescription]);
                    }
                }];           
            } else {
                DLog(@"Error saving child, error: %@", [childError localizedDescription]);
            }
        }];
    }
```

If there is a better way to handle such situation, please share. Thanks.

By saving context in background thread I don't see UI getting freeze. Posting question to know other better ways and learn more on core data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer having at least 2 contexts.

The main one associated with the persistent store (with no parent contexts) is `privateQueueConcurrencyType` so that UI is not affected during the saves to disk.

The second one is viewContext for UI which is the child context for the privateContext.

I usually have another one for background import which is a child context of the UI context and is configured as `privateQueueConcurrencyType` so it doesn't block the UI. When saved, the UI gets updated, and then changes are saved to the persistent store (when saved recursively).

Also, I create disposable child contexts to the viewContext whenever I will be making changes. I make the changes in the childContext then save recursively. I find this way saved my butt multiple time in multi-user situations.

Below is my setup:

```
lazy var privateSaveContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    moc.name = "privateSaveContext"
    moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.coordinator
    moc.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    return moc
}()

lazy var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    moc.name = "viewContext"
    moc.parent = self.privateSaveContext
    moc.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    return moc
}()

lazy var importContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    moc.name = "importContext"
    moc.parent = self.viewContext
    moc.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    return moc
}()
```

When saving to disk, I save recursively:

```
class func save(_ moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    moc.performAndWait {
        if moc.hasChanges {
            DLog("Inserted objects count = \(moc.insertedObjects.count)")
            do {
                try moc.save()
                if moc.parent == nil { DLog("SAVED changes to persistent store") }
                DLog("SAVED context '\(moc)'")
            } catch {
                DLog("ERROR saving context '\(moc)' - \(error)")
            }
        } else {
            if moc.parent == nil { DLog("SKIPPED saving changes to persistent store, because there are no changes") }
            DLog("SKIPPED saving context '\(moc)' because there are no changes")
        }
        if let parentContext = moc.parent {
            save(parentContext)
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. `DLog` is something I use so that it prints out the function name, date, time etc. You can simply change that to `print`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing details. I like the way you do it If I have to fetch new data while displaying view. In my case I have private and main context to fetch in background and to update UI respectively. Thanks again for your reply. (Yet to get the rights to vote :))

Comment: You can always accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: **Sure!** @oyalhi